# movieplayercontroller doesn't work

Tags: ios, video-streaming

I want to stream video on my iOS application, the problem is that it displays a black screen with the url I want to show but it works with other url's here is my code :

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://livevideo.infomaniak.com/iframe.php?stream=arabelfmendirect&name=arabel_webtv&player=2828.m3u8"];

moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
// moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

how can I fix it ?

Comment: The mentioned URL doesn't exist. I get 404. You can check if a stream works or not by opening them in the safari browser

Comment: Thank you for replaying here is the URL : `http://livevideo.infomaniak.com/iframe.php?stream=arabelfmendirect&name=arabel_webtv&player=2828.m3u8`

Answer (score 0):

The video URL mentioned doesn't use HLS format. Thus `MPMoviePlayerController` cannot play the video.

From http://livevideo.infomaniak.com/iframe.php?stream=arabelfmendirect&name=arabel_‌​webtv&player=2828.m3u8, it looks like it needs flash to play the video.

Comment: Could you give me tutorial or example on how to display video from this url please ?

Comment: What type of format used by this url ? I need to display the video but I have no idea on how to do it !